# How can I rename all files and keep only the numbers of each file to be the same?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
static private void RenameFiles() {
    images = Directory.GetFiles(sf, "*.gif");
    for (x = 0; x < images.Length; x++) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Working on current file: " + images[x]);
        if (File.Exists(images[x])) {
            NewImages = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(images[x]);
            NewImages.Save(sf + "\\" + "radar" + counter.ToString("D6") + ".Gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            NewImages.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

For example the first file name now is: `radar_temp_directoryradar000002`
And the last file name is: `radar_temp_directoryradar008760`

What i want to do is in the end that the first file name will be: `radar000002`
The next file name will be: `radar000003`
The last file name will be: `radar008760`

To keep the numbers only to change the name from `radar_temp_directoryradar` to just `radar`.
The format should not be change now they are all Gif's so they should stay Gif's.

The way i'm doing it now it's just creating new files like the firs one is: `radar000001`
And the last one is: `radar008759`
And also the old files are kept.

I want to rename the existing files, not create new ones.

Comment: A *rename* is the same as a *move* operation in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Move` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) to rename a file.

To get the same number in the new name, use the old name as base instead of using a counter:

```
static private void RenameFiles() {
  images = Directory.GetFiles(sf, "*.gif");
  foreach (string name in images) {
    Console.WriteLine("Working on current file: " + name);
    string newName = name.Replace("radar_temp_directory", String.Empty);
    File.Move(name, newName);
  }
}
```

The code above assumes that there is no `radar_temp_directory` in the path names, if there could be you should get the file name and do the replacement on only that:

```
string newName = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(name), Path.GetFileName(name).Replace("radar_temp_directory", String.Empty));
```

Comment: Guffa it's working in general but the directory of newName is not the same as the variable: name. For example newName now is: C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\\radar000004.Gif And name is: C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\radar_temp_directory\radar_temp_directoryradar000004.Gif

Comment: It put radar000004 in C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station instead replacing the old file at: C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\radar_temp_directory

Comment: @user3596190: As the path also contains `radar_temp_directory` you need to use the other way of creating the new name, where it only changes the file name and leaves the path unchanged. Maybe you read the question before I added that part to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (File.Exists(images[x]))
{
    File.Move(images[x], "radar" + counter.ToString("D6") + ".gif");
}
```